# Adding new elements to accordion header (h3) tags and how to style the new element in the header

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hi guys I have an accordion and have added some **section** elements to the h3 tag. Something like this:

```
<h3>  <section>Title</section> <section>Name </section>  <section>Age</section> <section> Weight</section> </h3>
```

How could I style the contents of the section? I have tried styling it this way:

```
#accordion ui-accordion-header section {
    width:200px;
    float:left;     
}
```

but the style never gets applied. Are there any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: i think `ui-accordion-header` must be a class name so put `.` in front of it like `.ui-accordion-header`

Comment: Further than that it's not semantic to put sections inside of any heading element.  Each of those should be their own <h3>.

Comment: Thanks Amit - i had the . in my other class selectors but somehow missed this and never occured to me I was missing something. Thanks.

Comment: @Michael - yeah I realize it wasn't a best practice thing to do but you can't have multipe <h3> tags in the accordion as it simply breaks it. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: @sw6-KTBFFH An H3 with span tags inside it is semantic from a code standpoint.  What becomes really more the problem is that you have a number of words that don't form a cohesive sentence/heading.  Google will read your H3 as: "Title Name Age etc."  Instead of reading it as "Title." "Name." "Age.".  And that is, in my opinion, a pretty big issue, especially if the content within your accordion is essential to understanding the page.  So my suggestion would be 1 of the following:  Either drop the H3 entirely OR fix the accordion so you can have multiple H3's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem like you're missing `.` to target class `ui-accordion-header`, try this:

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-header section {
    width:200px;
    float:left;     
}
```